# How to push the installation of apk into android "app-private" folder?

Tags: android

with normal packaging of an android application, anyone can access the apk file from the system/app using backup tools. While i have noticed that the apk file that is stored in system/app-private cannot be saved unless the phone is rooted.

Can anyone please suggest me the method to make an android app installed in app-private folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this option can be set in Developer Console in Play Store in section Publishing options - Copy Protection. But this feature will be deprecated soon.